# Oracle + Zend Framework. Get one not null value of three fields

Tags: oracle, zend-framework

Is the following table:

**table**

*id (pk)*

- number
- string
- Bool (1 or 0)

  When completing the table - set the primary key. And one of the three fields takes the specified value.

  Required to get the data from this table as follows:
  **id -> value**
  Where value is one of the values ​​in this table.

  The question is whether you can only get the field - which has a value, ie, roughly **select id, number if is not null, string if is not null, bool if is not null**?)
  To obtain a no extra empty fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$select = ...
$select->columns(
    "id" => "id",
    "value" => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        "COALESCE(number_column_name, string_column_name, bool_column_name)"
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you :) small correction - "COALESCE(TO_CHAR(number_column_name), TO_CHAR(string_column_name), TO_CHAR(bool_column_name))"